# How do you spill part of a cell range in new Excel Calc engine?

Tags: excel-formula

I have gotten my hands on the new Excel features of spill range. Before doing a running sum of a column in excel I used to do the following:

```
=SUM(G$4:G4)
```

Then drag this formula down but now I want to spill this automatically according to the length of the spill in the referred column. I tried the following but it is not working:

```
=SUM(G$4:G4#)
```

How do I make this work?

As an example of data look at column G and H in the following table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just refer to the first cell of the spill funciton (i.e. where you entered the formula with a `#` suffix - it will automatically adjust to track the size of the spill function output

`=SUM(G4#)`

Comment: `=SUM(G$4:G4)` is a moving sum, not a total sum. As this is dragged it sums from `G4` to whatever row it is on the range, not the entire range.

Comment: Can you supply a screen shot of 2 examples of your input range to the sum and the output of the spill function. It’s not super clear what you are trying to do

Comment: So you want the sum function to spill based on the spill of the function in G4?

Comment: Look at the desired output in column H of the image (updated question). It is a running sum, not a total sum.